# How do I capture parent page's url (utm parameters) in iframe page,

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iframe, utm

I am using below code on page load, but it gives me below error

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            if (("" + Request.QueryString["utm_source"] == "") && ("" + Request.QueryString["utm_medium"] == "") || ("" + Request.QueryString["utm_source"] == null) && ("" + Request.QueryString["utm_medium"] == null))
            {
                lblSource.Text = "Direct/Referral";
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString.ToString() != null)
                    {
                        string abc = Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString.ToString();

                        string[] source = abc.Split('?');
                        string a1 = source[1];

                        a1 = a1.Substring(11);

                        string[] spl = a1.Split('&');

                        utm_source = spl[0];
                        string a2 = spl[1];

                        utm_medium = a2.Substring(11);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Response.Write(ex);
                    lblSource.Text = "Direct/Referral";
                }
            }
            //Response.Write(utm_source + " &nbsp;&nbsp;" + utm_medium);

                lblSource.Text = utm_source + " " + utm_medium;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are doing it correctly, but you need to put `null` checks first before using them. Following are some of codes that can be improved.

Use this `if(Request.UrlReferrer!=null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString))` instead of `if (Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString.ToString() != null)` .

Use this `Request.QueryString["utm_source"] != null` instead of `Request.QueryString["utm_source"] == ""`, because, it will try to covert it to string for comparison and  that value is `null` , it will error as `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`.

To get exact querystring, from iFrame you can do it like this , instead of string manipulations.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Uri parenturl = new Uri(Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString);
    string qyr = parenturl.Query;
    NameValueCollection col = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(qyr);
    String kvalue = col["k"];
    String mvalue = col["m"];
}
```

**Assumption:**  The above code belongs to `test1.aspx` and i have one more page `test2.aspx` which has `iFrame` with `src` = `test1.aspx` . I have used `http://localhost:52785/test2.aspx?k=1&m=2` url, so parent page has querystrings as `k=1, m=2`. See below screenshot, what i got.

[image]

Comment: Dear @Arindam, thanks for the solution, but its not working. it giving me error of 
 "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Can you tell me on which line it shows error? Or if you are able to debug, then you can check .

Comment: Hi Arindam, it was some other silly error, otherwise your code is very helpful. THANKS A LOT.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following JavaScript, but only if the iframe and the site around come from the same domain (same origin policy).

```
var uri = document.getElementById("IdOfIframe").contentWindow.location.href;
```

Comment: Hey Daniel, My problem is Site and iframe both are on different servers. :(